# Visual Studio 2012 - Git is showing changes to multiple branches when I switch back and forth

Tags: visual-studio, git, branch

I am using Visual Studio 2012 along with Git Extensions.  Everything had been working fine (as far as I could tell), but now when I make a change in one of my branches, it is showing up in my other branch.  It is changes both branches at the same time....any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't commit your change, it "travels" to another branch that you switch to. While you may have multiple branches, you only have 1 working directory. What I usually do is:

```
git stash -u
```

then switch branch, experiment in VS. Then when I'm ready to go back, I

```
git stash pop
```

and it returns to the changes I had.

A common workflow is

```
git stash -u
git checkout someotherbranch
# experiment
git checkout -
git stash pop
```

Using the command line is really good as you get history. Try going with just msysgit for a while and you'll see the advantages of history, piping, tab-completion, etc.

btw, `git checkout -` works just like `cd -`, allowing you to continually switch between 2 places. Very useful.